# Rotate d3.parset visualization 90 degrees (make horizontal instead of vertical)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am using [d3 parsets](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-parsets) to create a d3 visualization. I am creating my visualization following the example code:

```js
var chart = d3.parsets()
  .dimensions(["Survived", "Sex", "Age", "Class"]);

var vis = d3.select("#vis").append("svg")
  .attr("width", chart.width())
  .attr("height", chart.height());

d3.csv("https://www.jasondavies.com/parallel-sets/titanic.csv", function(error, csv) {
  vis.datum(csv).call(chart);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://www.jasondavies.com/parallel-sets/d3.parsets.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://www.jasondavies.com/parallel-sets/d3.parsets.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="vis"></div>
</body>
```

Is there an easy way to rotate the end result by 90 degrees (i.e., see flow from left to right instead of top to bottom)?

Comment: `.attr("transform", "rotate(90)")` should rotate an element within your SVG. If it's possible, add a `g` element within the SVG which contains the chart and use it on that. `d3.select("#chartG").attr("transform", "rotate(90)")`. You may need to also set the `transform-origin` [property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone asked me about this a while back, and I made [this example](https://www.jasondavies.com/parallel-sets/rotate.html).